# Why on the first pic code doen't execute, but on the second it does?

Tags: c#

Exactly i know how to solve this problem, but i don't understand why this solution works.

I mean what the first( 1 ) piece of code dosn't output anything, but the second(2) works correctly.

I need an explanation -  why.

(1).

```cs
    class Greetings
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            cube(5);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static int cube(int num)
        {
            int result = num * num;
            return result;
        }
    }
```

(2).

```cs
    class Greetings
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cube(5));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static int cube(int num)
        {
            int result = num * num * num;
            return result;
        }
    }
```

It has to output 125, but it doesn't output anything.

Comment: Because you didn't tell it to write anything to the console in the first one.

Comment: Only `Console.WriteLine` prints stuff to the console. Did you ever write `Console.WriteLine` in the first code?

Comment: Why should version 1 output anything? Output to console is done by `Console.WriteLine`. That is the reason, why version 2 works.

Comment: Oh, thanks.I didn't expect that it was so easy.Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't print the answer with the `Console.WriteLine();` method in the first piece of code. The result is returned but not printed to the console, because there is no `Console.WriteLine();`.